# TFS 2017 Calculate bugs estimation with Stories estimation on Sprints

Tags: tfs, user-stories, sprint

I have just noticed that all my bugs in the Sprint (managed at the same level as Stories by Sprint configuration) are not calculated in to total times on the right bar in Sprint view.

So now for each bug i need the developer to open a Task? I just can't see the logic doing that as it seems like adding work where there is no need.

If i change the setting in the Sprint to handle bugs under stories, again i find myself with the same problem only this time i need to open a Story for each bug.

Assuming my bugs has a different priority, i can't just group them all in a single Story. So again i find myself opening a Story for each bug (usually will include the same text).

So is there any other solution? Where i can see bugs and Stories in the sprint and have the right bar show the total remaining work to be done including ALL the WIT in the Sprints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you opt to treat bugs as requirements, they're handled the exact same way as any other requirement. That means that yes, you need to create tasks underneath it to track hours. Requirements work off of points, tasks work off of hours. You've hit upon the solution already: Create tasks underneath the bug.

You're only considering one scenario: It's an obvious bug with a simple fix. There are many other scenarios to consider:

- Maybe there are multiple tasks involved in correcting a bug.
- Maybe the developer needs to do analysis in order to *find* the bug before they can *fix* it, and wants to track the analysis as a separate task.
- Maybe there's a task necessary to *verify* the fix that needs to be assigned to someone else.